# How can I get div to move up and down on hover? Mouseover and Mouseout conflict

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, mouseevent

I am trying to use run an animation using setInterval which works quiet well. Although I am trying to get the animation to run all the way through and then stop after mouse out.

I can get the div to move up and down but if you move the mouse in and out too fast it get's stuck in a loop of adding and subtracting pixels. Or other times it will stop moving altogether and get stuck at the top of bottom.

You can see the issue here, move the mouse in and out of the small box a few times fast.
https://jsfiddle.net/L16fdbrj/1/

Here is my Javascript:

```
    var blog_folder_index = false;
    var blog_folder_pos = 0;
    var blog_folder_interval;
    var framespeed = 5;

    function blog_folder_mouseover()
        {
            if (blog_folder_index == false)
                {
                    document.getElementById("blog_folder_button").style.cursor = "pointer";
                blog_folder_interval = setInterval(function (){ blog_folder_add();}, 35);   
                }
        }

    function blog_folder_mouseout()
        {
            blog_folder_interval = setInterval(function (){ blog_folder_subtract();}, 50);
            console.log("mouseout");        
        }

    function blog_folder_add()
        {
            if (blog_folder_pos <= -30)
                {
                    console.log(blog_folder_pos);
                    stop_function();
                }
            else if (blog_folder_pos > -30)
                {
                    blog_folder_pos -= framespeed; 
                    document.getElementById("blog_folder").style.marginTop = blog_folder_pos + 'px '; 
                }
        }

    function blog_folder_subtract()
        {
            if (blog_folder_pos >= 0)
                {
                    console.log(blog_folder_pos);
                    stop_function();
                }
            else if (blog_folder_pos < 0)
                {
                    blog_folder_pos += framespeed; 
                    document.getElementById("blog_folder").style.marginTop = blog_folder_pos + 'px '; 
                }
        }   

    function blog_folder_click()
        {

            blog_folder_index = true;
            portfolio_folder_index = false;
            about_folder_index = false;
            document.getElementById("blog_folder_button").style.cursor = "default";

            document.getElementById("portfolio_folder").style.zIndex = "2";
            document.getElementById("blog_folder").style.zIndex = "3";
            document.getElementById("about_folder").style.zIndex = "1";


            blog_folder_interval = setInterval(function (){ blog_folder_subtract();}, 35);
        }

    function stop_function()
        {
            clearInterval(blog_folder_interval);
        }
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, use CSS animation.
If you have to use javascript, then try jQuery.
Also if you dont want to use jQuery then use requestAnimationFrame with polyfill instead of setTimeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to clear your previous interval before creating a new one:

https://jsfiddle.net/L16fdbrj/2/

```
function blog_folder_mouseover() {
    if (blog_folder_index == false) {
        document.getElementById("blog_folder_button").style.cursor = "pointer";

        // clear previous interval
        stop_function();

        blog_folder_interval = setInterval(function () {
            blog_folder_add();
        }, 35);
    }
}

function blog_folder_mouseout() {
    // clear previous interval
    stop_function();

    blog_folder_interval = setInterval(function () {
        blog_folder_subtract();
    }, 50);
    console.log("mouseout");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been looking at the code to long that I didn't even realize I was creating multiple intervals. One question though, You triggered the stop function instead of running a clear interval. I didn't know I could call a function in the middle of another function and still have it finish. What I'm wondering, is the stop function running at the same time or are the mouse functions paused while the stop function goes?

Comment: javascript runs on a single thread so nothing runs in parallel.  Mouse events that happen while the code is executing will however be queued to get processed when the code completes.  Clearing an interval though is really really fast.